# New uploaded build not showing in iTunes Connect after failed upload

Tags: ios, xcode

I uploaded a build for version 4.0.0 of my app from Xcode, and that showed up in iTunes Connect but I couldn't submit it because it didn't have a marketing icon. So I added the marketing icon and uploaded the new version as 4.0.1, but it's not showing up in iTunes Connect after over 48 hours. I still only see version 4. Trying to re-upload 4.0.1 just gives me an error saying that version is already uploaded, so it should be there.

Comment: You can change build number for version 4.0.1 from 1.0.0 or 1.0 to 1.0.1 and try upload again..

Answer (score 0):

Change the build number in Xcode to avoid that error. You can submit app multiple times with same version by changing the build number. Refer screenshot below.

[image]